# XCOPY command to copy files to SAN Storage

Tags: copy, storage, xcopy, san

Is there any command to transfer files to SAN storage usin xcopy? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

SAN storage devices are typically of 2 classes: NAS and Block. The first use file-level access, i.e. use NFS, SMB/CIFS and etc (even FTP) to transfer files there.

Block-storage devices provide their space as raw drive-space, which is used as drives on the servers. So you have to attach the drive, create a new or mount an existing file-system to be able to copy files there.